# I want to convert each frame of a animated sprite into a separate Layer and then create a sprite sheet

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want to convert each frame of a animated sprite  into a separate Layer and then create a sprite sheet , can anyone Provide steps to do the same[Here is the image of the frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc44T.png)

I have tried asking AI for solution but no progress so far